What is the correct way to find % variance between two scores?
I want to calculate % variance (or deviation) between two scores ie what was the improvement +- from Score A to Score B. I usually use this below method:
(A-B)/A*% Where A is my original score and B is my new score. This method works fine till A is not Zero, the moment A score is zero the calculation fails.
How do i find % variance when my score changed from 0 to say 40?

What is the meaning of variance in that case?

Yes i get it but I want to like show % change from original score to new score and how do i do that is a question for me.

In the case of an initial value of $0$, relative/percentage change is undefined. There is no number that can multiply $0$ to reach a nonzero number. Compare this with the problem of division by zero.

The percentage change (variance is the wrong word to use since it means something completely different) is a quantitative measure. It doesn't really make sense when there's been a qualitative change to something from nothing. If you start with nothing, then any percentage increase will still leave you with nothing.
You could say "the percentage change is infinite", but that's not really helpful since it doesn't tell you anything about the new score, other than it's positive.

Thank you. I understand!
